# Efficiently Determine if EF 4 POCO Already in ObjectSet

Tags: poco, entity-framework-4, persistence-ignorance

I'm trying EF 4 with POCO's on a small project for the first time.  In my Repository implementation, I want to provide a method AddOrUpdate that will add a passed-in POCO to the repository if it's new, else do nothing (as the updated POCO will be saved when SaveChanges is called).

My first thought was to do this:

```
public void AddOrUpdate(Poco p)
{
    if (!Ctx.Pocos.Contains<Poco>(p))
    {
        Ctx.Pocos.AddObject(p);
    }
}
```

However that results in a `NotSupportedException` as documented under [Referencing Non-Scalar Variables Not Supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx) (bonus question: why would that not be supported?)

Just removing the `Contains` part and always calling AddObject results in an `InvalidStateException`:

> An object with the same key already
>   exists in the ObjectStateManager. The
>   existing object is in the Unchanged
>   state. An object can only be added to
>   the ObjectStateManager again if it is
>   in the added state.

So clearly EF 4 knows somewhere that this is a duplicate based on the key.

What's a clean, efficient way for the Repository to update Pocos for either a new or pre-existing object when AddOrUpdate is called so that the subsequent call to SaveChanges() will do the right thing?

I did consider carrying an isNew flag on the object itself, but I'm trying to take persistence ignorance as far as practical.

Comment: Ah yes it seems you too have managed to avoid falling in the EF4 pit of success.

Comment: @Will: I'm strongly considering NHibernate with S#arpArchitect, but it looks like they're just now starting to support VS2010 and .Net 4.  Not sure if that path will be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look at [ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679461%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), it is good described in [this stackoverflow queston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715501/is-is-possible-to-check-if-an-object-is-already-attached-to-a-data-context-in-ent).