# CannotDelete Entity in Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is my  Code,

```
  db.Set<T>().Remove(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

And i got this error.

```
{"The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."}
```

i tried many ways to fix that problem, but i couldn't. How can id fix ?

thank you all.

Comment: Please try to show what exactly you tried and why that didn't help. See for example [The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791149/the-object-cannot-be-deleted-because-it-was-not-found-in-the-objectstatemanager). If you think none of the questions you found apply to your situation, you should show where `item` comes from.

Comment: thank you for your help but i already tried ways on that link

Comment: Then explain what happened when you tried that. What is told on that link should work.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are trying to remove an object that doesn't come from your DbContext. For example if your object comes from a web form in ASP .Net MVC it has noting to do with the database until you attach it to the database.

There are 2 things you can do to be able to remove your item:

```
db.Set<T>.Attach(item);
// now you should be able to remove it
```

or

```
item = db.Set<T>.Single(x => x.Id == itme.Id);
// now you should be able to remove it
```

**EDIT**

You should also make sure that you're not trying to attach an object that already is attached. Take a look at the [EntitState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate.aspx):

db.Entry(item).State

Comment: thank you for your help but;
when is use db.Set<T>().Attach(item) i got this error {"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."}

Comment: item = db.Set<T>.Single(x => x.Id == itme.Id);
i can't use like this beacuse visual studio does not know entity TYPE

Comment: i really don't understand when i track entity db.Entry(item).State is Detached  and when i use db.Set<T>().Attach(item) i got exception like this             {"An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."}

Comment: @DursunICCAN Maybe you have multiple instances of you DbContext at the same time and there are conflict between them?