# Delete using LINQ to entityVB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have this code for delete row in database by using LINQ to Entity in VB.net and when run i just receive a error message like that:

> this object cannot be delete because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataList
    Dim staffCd As String = row.Cells(Col_fCode).Value.ToString
    Dim deleteRow = From p In REMSDemoDB.W_frmMST020_A0_0 _
                              Where p.staffCD.Contains(staffCd) _
                              Select p
    REMSDemoDB.DeleteObject(deleteRow)
Next
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: you might want to refer to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791149/the-object-cannot-be-deleted-because-it-was-not-found-in-the-objectstatemanager

Answer (score 0):

The result of

```
From p In REMSDemoDB.W_frmMST020_A0_0 _
          Where p.staffCD.Contains(staffCd) _
          Select p
```

is an `IQueryable(Of T)`, not one instance.

You should get the instance to delete, e.g. by

```
REMSDemoDB.DeleteObject(deleteRow.FirstOrdefault())
```

(and check if it's not null).