# .RemoveRange Without fetching database records first in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am deleting the multiple records from the database using the .RemoveRange, but for that I have to fetch all the records first and then I pass them to the .RemoveRange, but I want to achieve that without fetching the records from the databas?
any idea how to achieve that?

```
db.People.RemoveRange(just giving the ids or list of ids of people class);
```

Comment: Try to create entities with new, assign the ID, then pass it to the function.

Comment: Yes doing it like that
 List<ResidentAppointment> ra1 = new List<ResidentAppointment>();
                    ra1.Add(new ResidentAppointment { Id = appointmentId });
                    _context.ResidentAppointments.RemoveRange(ra1);
but getting error like that
the object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the objectstatemanager. entity framework

Comment: I have other ways of doing it, but I want it from .RemoveRange because it is very fast and is done perfectly.

Comment: You have to attach the entity first, have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19422173/3936440

Comment: I have list of entities, can you please tell me how can I attach the list of entities at once?

Comment: I would say: `db.People.Attach({your_entity_created_with_new})`

Comment: @ ViRuSTriNiTy  .I have done that by attaching the entities first.
thanks it is working...

Comment: I posted an answer so you can mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create entities with `new`, assign the ID, then attach the entity like

`db.People.Attach({your_entity_created_with_new})`

and finally pass the entities to `RemoveRange()`.

Comment: But this only works for the Primery key and not for other properties in the class. but working fine...

Comment: With EF Core I didn;t even have to Attach(). RemoveRange() is sufficient

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [EntityFramework.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended/6.1.0.168) library, with it you can write:

```
db.People.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).Delete();
```

Comment: Will it call to database only once and is it a fast way of doing that?

Comment: This would fetch the data from DB first, exactly the thing @Ali tries to avoid.

Comment: @AliNafees, yes it will not fetch data from database. You can read [this](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.Extended#batch-update-and-delete)

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov It will not? Are you sure as .Where() is a condition and how should the library know which IDs are present without looking into the DB.

Comment: @ ViRuSTriNiTy I also have asked the same thing and let me check his link?

Comment: From documentation: Batch update and delete **eliminates the need to retrieve and load** an entity before modifying it

Comment: Hey I have achieved that without using the Library and I would like to mark correct answer for the person who have said that do that by attaching first the entities. but thanks for your answer as well...

Comment: @AliNafees, attaching will work **only at case of Ids** filter, if you later will want to delete rows with custom filter, like `Where(x => x.Age > 20)`, it will not work.

Comment: Yes but in this scnerio I was not needed to do for filtered first, and also I am avoiding installing the library first.main reason is I not want to install library