# EF : related entities are set as INSERT instead of being only referenced to the added entity

Tags: frameworks, entity, relationships

I tried to find an answer through the related questions I got but I didn't see the same situation I have now. I a beginner with this framework.
The thing is that in the DB the  TopicFeedbackType  is always referred but TopicNavigatedUrl  and Product are always inserted event if I attach the entity. What am I doing wrong? I attach the found entity to the correct entity set name. The entity gets attached. I noticed that before the p_TopicQuickFb have one of its property updated by an attached entity, its EntityKey is null, but when the currentNavUrl(for example) is set, the EntityKey of p_TopicQuickFb is not null anymore. Its value is "EntitySet=TopicQuickFeedbacks" but there is no id.
I am really lost in there.

```
    public void AddTopicQuickFeedback(TopicQuickFeedback p_TopicQuickFb, string p_SessionID)
    {
            TopicFeedbackType currentType = this.GetTopicFeedbackType(p_TopicQuickFb.TopicFeedbackType.FeedbackType);
            bool currentTypeAttached = false;

            TopicNavigatedUrl currentNavUrl = this.GetTopicNavigatedUrl(p_TopicQuickFb.TopicNavigatedUrl.Url);
            bool currentNavUrlAttached = false;

            Product currentProduct = this.GetProduct(p_TopicQuickFb.Product.Name, p_TopicQuickFb.Product.MajorVersion, p_TopicQuickFb.Product.MinorVersion);
            bool currentProductAttached = false;

            using (COHFeedbackEntities context = GetObjectContext())
            {
                TopicFeedback tf = GetTopicFeedback(p_SessionID, context);
                if (tf != null)
                {

                    if (currentType != null)
                    {
                        p_TopicQuickFb.TopicFeedbackType = null;
                        context.AttachToOrGet<TopicFeedbackType>("TopicFeedbackTypes", ref currentType);                   
                        currentTypeAttached = true;                            
                        p_TopicQuickFb.TopicFeedbackType = currentType;
                    }

                    if (currentNavUrl != null)
                    {
                        p_TopicQuickFb.TopicNavigatedUrl = null;
                        context.AttachToOrGet<TopicNavigatedUrl>("TopicNavigatedUrls", ref currentNavUrl);                         
                        currentNavUrlAttached = true;  
                        p_TopicQuickFb.TopicNavigatedUrl = currentNavUrl;
                    }

                    if (currentProduct != null)
                    {
                        p_TopicQuickFb.Product = null;
                        context.AttachToOrGet<Product>("Products", ref currentProduct);                  
                        currentProductAttached = true;  
                        p_TopicQuickFb.Product = currentProduct;
                    }

                    tf.TopicQuickFeedbacks.Add(p_TopicQuickFb);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    context.Detach(tf);

                    if (currentNavUrlAttached)
                    {
                        context.TopicNavigatedUrls.Detach(currentNavUrl);
                    }
                    if (currentProductAttached)
                    {
                        context.Products.Detach(currentProduct);
                    }
                    if (currentTypeAttached)
                    {
                        context.TopicFeedbackTypes.Detach(currentType);
                    }
                }
            }
      }
```

I found the method in this post : [Is is possible to check if an object is already attached to a data context in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715501/is-is-possible-to-check-if-an-object-is-already-attached-to-a-data-context-in-en/1716109#1716109)

```
    public static void AttachToOrGet<T>(this System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext context, string entitySetName, ref T entity)
        where T : IEntityWithKey
    {
          System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateEntry entry;
          // Track whether we need to perform an attach
          bool attach = false;
          if (
                context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry
                      (
                        context.CreateEntityKey(entitySetName, entity),
                        out entry
                      )
            )
          {
                // Re-attach if necessary
                attach = entry.State == EntityState.Detached;
                // Get the discovered entity to the ref
                entity = (T)entry.Entity;
          }
          else
          {
                // Attach for the first time
                attach = true;
          }
        if (attach)
        {
            context.AttachTo(entitySetName, entity);
        }
    }
```

Test method:

```
        User user = new User(true, false, false);
        string commentStr = "This is my comment";

        Product product = new Product("ProductName", 7, 0);

        TopicFeedbackComment commFeedback = new TopicFeedbackComment(commentStr, new TopicNavigatedUrl("http://testurl.com/test0"), product);

        TopicFeedback feedback = new TopicFeedback(sessionID, user, FeedbackState.New);


        provider.AddTopicFeedback(feedback);

        TopicFeedback addedFeedback = provider.RetrieveTopicFeedback(sessionID);

        provider.AddTopicFeedbackComment(commFeedback, sessionID);
```

Running this again and again do just INSERT to the

Can't post images so I can provide schema it if necessary.

Comment: I found it by myself.
Assigning the entity was wrong.
Like : p_TopicQuickFb.TopicFeedbackType = currentType;
The correct solution is to assign only the id and keep null the property when the entity is attached
Like: p_TopicQuickFb.TopicFeedbackTypeID = currentType.Id;
Hope this will help some!!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is in my last comment. I found it by myself.

If someone would like to comment why it's working this way it would be nice! :)